# How to interface with iOS lockdownd

Tags: tcp, ios

I used nmap to portscan my iPod Touch, and found a single port open, which was port 62078, labeled as "iphone-sync". I did some research, and found that the proccess behind it was a program called  "lockdownd" which could be used to interface with the iPod.

I was wondering if and how I could use this to interface with and possibly control my iPod.

Comment: iTunes is pretty good at interfacing with and controlling iOS devices.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Port 62078 is the port on which the iOS [`lockdown`](https://theiphonewiki.com/wiki/Usbmux#lockdownd_protocol) daemon listens on. Normally it is interacted with via [`usbmuxd`](https://theiphonewiki.com/wiki/Usbmux) which is a protocol that allows arbitrary TCP connections to be made over a USB connection.

`lockdownd` can be used to do a lot of nifty things with the built-in services Apple expose on unjailbroken devices. The goto library for interfacing with this service seems to be [libimobiledevice](http://libimobiledevice.org) which is an open-source library implementing the `usbmuxd` and other iOS protocols. For a better overview of the capabilities of `lockdownd` and the iMobileDevice library, take a look at some of the packaged [tools](http://www.libimobiledevice.org/docs/html/files.html) the library provides. If you know C, the source code for these tools is [here](https://github.com/libimobiledevice/libimobiledevice/tree/master/tools).

Answer (score 0):

Obviously (and someone has already mentioned this in a comment), it can be used for syncing the device over WiFi because iTunes does it.

However, the interface is undocumented, and as such unsupported by Apple.

Another option, if you are looking at controlling the device remotely and generally having fun with it, would be to jailbreak it and writing your own control software that would run on the phone. That would allow you to connect over an interface you would create yourself.

Such software may even already exist in the jailbreak community.